# Determining if a series of functions is uniformly convergent with L Hopital's Rule

Tags: limits, functions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Hi Guys was attempting this question and was wondering if I was doing the question correctly?

Determine whether or not the sequence of functions is uniformly convergent:-

$$h_n:[0,3]\to \mathbb{R}$$
$$h_n(x) = \frac{n^2x^3}{n^3+x}, x\in[0,3]$$

Checking point wise convergence first

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}h_n(x) =  \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2x^3}{n^3+x}$$

Applying L Hopital's Rule

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}h_n(x) = x^3 \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n}{3n^2} = x^3 \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2}{3n} = x^3 \frac{2}{3} \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} $$

$$x^3 \frac{2}{3} \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$$

$$Therefore \lim_{n\to \infty}h_n(x) = h(x) = 0$$

Checking for uniformly convergent

$$M_n =  sup|h_n(x)-h(x)|,x\in [0,3]$$

$$|h_n(x)-h(x)|$$

$$\frac{n^2x^3}{n^3+x}$$

is it accurate to say the following when checking to see uniform convergence

$$\frac{n^2x^3}{(n^3+x)} < \frac{n^2}{n^3} <\frac{1}{n} = 0 $$

$$\lim{n \to \infty} $$

hence the sequence of functions is indeed uniformly convergent ?

Comment: The general approach is sound! The specific inequality $\frac{n^2x^3}{(n^3+x)} < \frac{n^2}{n^3}$ doesn't seem correct, but the variant $\frac{n^2x^3}{(n^3+x)} < \frac{n^23^3}{n^3}$ should work.

Comment: thats what i was considering since the question stated closed interval [0,3] while evaluating the question i was confused about looking at the expressions and breaking down as i stated above in the question. But i also gave consideration for when x is at its largest value which is 3 you will get what you stated and so i wasn't sure. $$\frac{27}{n}$$ as n goes to $\infty$ you will get 0. This is the general porblem i am having when evaluating the sup |$f_n(x)-f(x)$|

Comment: Thanks @Greg Martin for the confirmation and the correction greatly appreciated.